# hide a widget to users without group on a forum with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forum

I'm admin on a forum (forumactif) and I'm trying to hide a sliding page (which is visible on every pages of the forum), a widget to several groups. What I ideally want is to hide my widget (my sliding page, in an iframe) to all the users who are not in groups. It is preferable to use jQuery.

```
if ($(".mydiv img[title='MYTITLE']")) {
    $("#myid").css("display", "block");
}
```

I'm using the title of ranks. If the users have the rank, they are allowed to see the widget, otherwise, they can't. I can't get it to work.

Comment: could you relpicate this on plunker/fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery to hide an element that only a certain usergroup should see isn't secure as JQuery can be seen and modified in browser developer tools.

I suggest you read your forum documentation on obtaining the usergroup of the current user and then doing something like:

```
if($usergroup >= 4):
    // show widget...
endif;
```

An example using [MyBB](http://community.mybb.com/) forums is:

```
require_once 'global.php';
if($mybb->user['usergroup'] >= 4):
    // show widget
endif;
```

So check your Software documentation on doing so.

Comment: thanks for your help, it doesn't want to work, I don't know where I can have the software documentation

    `if($phpbb2->user['usergroup'] >= 0):
     $('#myid').css('display', 'block');
    endif;`

Comment: No I mean, locate where it is being displayed in your template files and then wrap it in an if statement :) Then you'll never need to use JQuery because it just won't get outputted if they are usergroup 0. @erin0